# iPad/iPhone on iOS 5 - images don't always load in Safari, just on my network

Tags: ios, network, iphone, mobile-safari, ipad

This question is baffling to say the least, as I'm just not sure how to diagnose where the problem is happening.

Here's the problem: when I am connected to my network in the office (but not on other networks), the iPads or iPhones (all running latest iOS) sometimes don't show all of the images in Safari, and you have to reload the page (sometimes several times) to get all of the images to load. This was never an issue with prior iOS builds (prior to version 5).

This never happens on any other network - for example at the Apple Store, or cafe wifi networks.

Our office setup is as follows:

D-Link 4 Port Modem Router DSL-526B connected to ADSL2+ service
connected to:
D-Link NetDefend SOHO UTM Firewall DFL-160
connected to:
D-Link 16-Port WebSmart Gigabit Switch DGS-1210-16

Nothing has changed with the aforementioned setup between going from iOS 4 to 5. And we're seeing it with both iPad 2s and 3rd-generation iPads and with iPhone 4/4S

What could be happening for this to be a problem with our network? We don't have any issues with our Macs.

Comment: I should probably have added that there is a current generation Airport Extreme connected to the switch which services WiFi. Both channels have been tried (including the 5GHz channel) and I've also tried an older Airport Extreme and an older Time Capsule. Same deal with all.

Comment: Sounds like you've taken the WiFi out of the equation by trying different ones, but have you done the same with the D-Link firewall and switch? Basic troubleshooting - remove all the variables you can (where possible), then start adding them back in to try and identify the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Tough one.  Definitely need to see more troubleshooting.  Some places to start:

- Find an image that the iPads are having difficulty loading, then open just that image in a separate page in Safari.  Any problem loading and reloading the image on a page by itself?
- How many WiFi devices are being served by one base station?  At some point it gets overloaded with sheer volume of requests, even if the data transfer is small.
- Is the WiFi base station doing NAT, possibly leading to a double-NAT setup that will clog the local network with failed connections?  You would still be able to browse the web, but overall network performance would suffer.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issues and performed a couple of steps that seemed to help.

1. Disable ipv6 in the routers. Of course, this assumes you are not using ipv6. I believe this step gave me the most improvement.
2. Restrict your wifi to the minimum number of standards needed. For example, if all the devices are N-capable, limit your wifi network to that standard.

Comment: How can you accomplish these things on an iPad/iPhone?

Comment: I focused on the router(s). I am not sure it is necessary or possible to disable the settings on the devices themselves.